# Change view controller using swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want to use swipe gesture to move to another view controller using right direction. Can you help me?

```
@IBAction func right(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    // what I must write here

}
```

Comment: use pagview controller

Answer (score 2):

**Just write one line code -**

```
@IBAction func right(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

     if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:

          self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nextView", sender: self)

          break
        default:
            break
        }
    }


}
```